# Python re.sub strip leading/trailing whitespace within quotes

Tags: python, regex

I want to use re.sub to remove leading and trailing whitespace from single-quoted strings embedded in a larger string. If I have, say,

```
textin  = " foo '  bar nox ': glop ,' frox ' "
```

I want to produce

```
desired = " foo 'bar nox': glop ,'frox' "
```

Removing the leading whitespace is relatively straightforward.

```
>>> lstripped = re.sub(r"'\s*([^']*')", r"'\1", textin)    
>>> lstripped
" foo 'bar nox ': glop ,'frox ' "
```

The problem is removing the trailing whitespace. I tried, for example,

```
>>> rstripped = re.sub(r"('[^']*)(\s*')", r"\1'", lstripped)
>>> rstripped
" foo 'bar nox ': glop ,'frox ' "
```

but that fails because the `[^']*` matches the trailing whitespace.

I thought about using lookback patterns, but the Re doc says they can only contain fixed-length patterns.

I'm sure this is a previously solved problem but I'm stumped.

Thanks!

EDIT: The solution needs to handle strings containing a single non-whitespace character and empty strings, i.e. `' p ' --> 'p'` and `'  '  --> ''`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`[^\']*` - is greedy, i.e. it includes also spaces and/or tabs, so let's use non-greedy one: `[^\']*?`

```
In [66]: re.sub(r'\'\s*([^\']*?)\s*\'','\'\\1\'', textin)
Out[66]: " foo 'bar nox': glop ,'frox' "
```

Less escaped version:

```
re.sub(r"'\s*([^']*?)\s*'", r"'\1'", textin)
```

Comment: That works, thanks!  I'll mark it accepted if you'll add at least a little explanation of why the non-greedy '?' operator makes it work.  Also, do you mind if I edit to add a less escaped version like `re.sub(r"'\s*([^']*?)\s*'", r"'\1'", textin)` ?

Comment: @MikeEllis, it looks much better after you've edited it - thank you! :)

Answer (score 2):

The way to catch the whitespaces is by defining the previous 
* as non-greedy, instead of `r"('[^']*)(\s*')"` use `r"('[^']*?)(\s*')"`.

You can also catch both sides with a single regex:

```
stripped = re.sub("'\s*([^']*?)\s*'", r"'\1'", textin)
```

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work:

`'(\s*)(.*?)(\s*)'`

```
'      # an apostrophe
(\s*)  # 0 or more white-space characters (leading white-space)
(.*?)  # 0 or more any character, lazily matched (keep)
(\s*)  # 0 or more white-space characters (trailing white-space)
'      # an apostrophe
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/OL9u6x/2)